# Highcharts - Change opacity of chart when tooltip is shown

Tags: highcharts

When the tooltip is shown, is it possible to change the opacity of all data points in the chart, with the exception of the data point for which the label is currently shown?

i.e. in the default column chart, when the mouse moves over a column, that column will be highlighted a bit. For that same event, I'd like all other column's opacity to change to 50%.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use point mouseOver and mouseOut events callback functions in case of your chart. Inside this events you can update color of specific points. 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.point.events.mouseOver
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.point.events.mouseOut

If you will use rgba colors, you will  be able to set your opacity.

```
  point: {
    events: {
      mouseOver: function() {
        Highcharts.each(this.series.data, function(p, i) {
          p.update({
            color: 'rgba(50,120,60,0.5)'
          }, false)
        });
        this.update({
          color: 'rgba(50,120,60,1)'
        });
      },
      mouseOut: function() {
        Highcharts.each(this.series.data, function(p, i) {
          p.update({
            color: 'rgba(50,120,60,1)'
          }, false)
        });
        this.series.chart.redraw();
      },
    }
  }
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/4q10q8r1/

Kind regards.